# Additional calendars link on overlay is not working after applying KB 4484143(November, 2019)

Tags: calendar

After applying KB 4484143 patches on last Friday, addition Calendars link on overlay is not working.

Previous version is using, anchor tag: 
<a class="ms-acal-apanel-item ms-acal-apanel-color1" href="/sites/int/Lists/Apple/calendar.aspx"><span>Apple</span></a>

Latest update is using  span tag: <span>Apple</span>

I injected jquery block on ScriptEditor.
Please give me advise to fix this issue.

SharePoint is 2016 On-Prem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue although I suggest you open a ticket with Microsoft via support.microsoft.com/help. Ultimately, this is a product bug and not one we can assist you with.